# Inserting a string at particular position of line

Tags: shell, unix

I want to insert a string at particular position of line in file.

For example my file has content

file1:

```
abcd efg hi 
xxx yy   
zzccc
xx 7777
```

Now in each line where first character is x, I want to write "na" at the 11th position.

The output of file should be:

file1:

```
abcd efg hi 
xxx yy    na
zzccc
xx 7777   na
```

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: after posting question file is modified. First "xxx" is starting of 2nd line and next "xx" is starting of 4th line

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Do this: 
 
`perl -e 'while(<>){ if(/^x/){chomp; print $_." na\n";}else{print;}}' file1` 


Replace (/^x/) with whatever you  want and " na" with the string you want.

Answer (score 0):

A Bourne/Posix shell solution that presumes the lines containing `x` are 10 chars or less in your example would be:

```
$ while IFS= read -r line; do [ $(expr index "$line" x) -eq 1 ] && printf "%-10sna\n" "$line" || printf "%s\n" "$line"; done <file.txt
abcd efg hi
xxx yy    na
zzccc
xx 7777   na
```

In short script form it would be:

```
#!/bin/sh

while IFS= read -r line; do 
    if [ $(expr index "$line" x) -eq 1 ]; then 
        printf "%-10sna\n" "$line"
    else
        printf "%s\n" "$line"
    fi
done <file.txt
```

To edit your file in place using the script above, simply use a temporary file and redirect the output:

```
sh script.sh <file.txt >tmp && mv -f tmp file.txt
```

**Note:** this does not check whether `tmp` exists and will overwrite it if it does. If you need to check the length of the string to insure it does not exceed 10 characters, you can use `$(expr length "$line")` to find the length of each line. Another alternative to both `perl` and shell expressions would be `sed -i` to edit the file in place.

Answer (score 0):

`sed 's/\(^[x].*\)/\1 na/g' 1.t`

Comment: sorry with add 11th pos condition updated `sed 's/\(^[x].*\)/\1           /g' file.t | sed 's/\(^[x].\{0,9\}\).*/\1na/g'`

Comment: I think this would benefit from a bit more explanation.